# MySQL query took 98 seconds to run but EXPLAIN looks okay

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a query that took 98 seconds to execute this morning, but I can't recreate the problem now, and the EXPLAIN output isn't giving me any clues. Am I missing something?

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT `a`.`name`        AS `ap_name`, 
       AVG(`s3`.`value`) AS `sas_value` 
FROM   `student` `s` 
       LEFT JOIN `student_assessment` `s2` 
              ON `s`.`id` = `s2`.`student_id` 
       LEFT JOIN `assessment_period` `a` 
              ON `s2`.`assessment_period_id` = `a`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `student_assessment_score` `s3` 
              ON `s2`.`id` = `s3`.`student_assessment_id` 
       LEFT JOIN `hierarchy_value_attribute_type` `h` 
              ON `s3`.`hierarchy_value_attribute_type_id` = `h`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `hierarchy_value` `h2` 
              ON `h`.`hierarchy_value_id` = `h2`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `hierarchy_type` `h3` 
              ON `h2`.`hierarchy_type_id` = `h3`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `assessment_type` `a2` 
              ON `a`.`assessment_type_id` = `a2`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `assessment_type_grade_level` `a3` 
              ON `s2`.`assessment_type_grade_level_id` = `a3`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `school_year` `s4` 
              ON `a`.`school_year_id` = `s4`.`id` 
WHERE  `a2`.`abbreviated_name` = 'PSS' 
       AND `h3`.`name` = 'Subject' 
       AND `h`.`name` = 'Scaled Score' 
       AND h2.name = 'Reading' 
       AND s.school_id = '112' 
       AND `a3`.`grade_level_id` = '8' 
GROUP  BY `h`.`name`, 
          `a`.`name` 
ORDER  BY `a`.`start_date`;
```

Here's the explain output:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: a3
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,assessment_type_grade_level_grade_level_id_grade_level_id
          key: assessment_type_grade_level_grade_level_id_grade_level_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 3
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: a2
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: a
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,assessment_period_assessment_type_id_assessment_type_id
          key: assessment_period_assessment_type_id_assessment_type_id
      key_len: 8
          ref: db.a2.id
         rows: 32
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s4
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: db.a.school_year_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s2
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,student_assessment_student_id_student_id,student_assessment_assessment_period_id_assessment_period_id,saai_3
          key: student_assessment_assessment_period_id_assessment_period_id
      key_len: 8
          ref: db.a.id
         rows: 733
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 6. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,student_school_id_school_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: db.s2.student_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 7. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s3
         type: ref
possible_keys: shhi_1,sssi_17
          key: sssi_17
      key_len: 8
          ref: db.s2.id
         rows: 5
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 8. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: h
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_hvat_name_idx,hhhi
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: db.s3.hierarchy_value_attribute_type_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 9. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: h2
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,indx_hierarchy_value_name_idx,hierarchy_value_hierarchy_type_id_hierarchy_type_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: db.h.hierarchy_value_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 10. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: h3
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_hierarchy_type_name_idx
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: db.h2.hierarchy_type_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's the entry in the slow query log:

```
# Time: 120601  7:22:01
# User@Host: #####
# Query_time: 98.279940  Lock_time: 0.000139 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1338549721;
SELECT  
`a`.`name` AS `ap_name`, AVG(`s3`.`value`) AS `sas_value` 
FROM `student` `s` 
LEFT JOIN `student_assessment` `s2` ON `s`.`id` = `s2`.`student_id` 
LEFT JOIN `assessment_period` `a` ON `s2`.`assessment_period_id` = `a`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `student_assessment_score` `s3` ON `s2`.`id` = `s3`.`student_assessment_id` 
LEFT JOIN `hierarchy_value_attribute_type` `h` ON `s3`.`hierarchy_value_attribute_type_id` = `h`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `hierarchy_value` `h2` ON `h`.`hierarchy_value_id` = `h2`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `hierarchy_type` `h3` ON `h2`.`hierarchy_type_id` = `h3`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `assessment_type` `a2` ON `a`.`assessment_type_id` = `a2`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `assessment_type_grade_level` `a3` ON `s2`.`assessment_type_grade_level_id` = `a3`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `school_year` `s4` ON `a`.`school_year_id` = `s4`.`id`WHERE `a2`.`abbreviated_name` = 'PSS' 
AND `h3`.`name` = 'Subject' 
AND `h`.`name` = 'Scaled Score' 
 AND h2.name = 'Reading'  AND s.school_id = '112'  AND `a3`.`grade_level_id` = '8'  GROUP BY `h`.`name`, `a`.`name` ORDER BY `a`.`start_date`;
```

Comment: Was the 98 seconds shortly after a server restart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a 10 tables query, 98 seconds could actually be OK.

Please note that under mysql your where clause:

```
       `a2`.`abbreviated_name` = 'PSS' 
   AND `h3`.`name` = 'Subject' 
   AND `h`.`name` = 'Scaled Score' 
   AND h2.name = 'Reading' 
   AND s.school_id = '112' 
   AND `a3`.`grade_level_id` = '8'
```

is implicitly canceling the LEFT JOINS, since each time you ask for "column=value", it means "column IS NOT NULL".
Use INNER JOINS instead of LEFT JOINS for the tables a2, h3, h, h2, s and a3, and add theses respective filters within the ON part of their respective INNER JOIN.

rgds.

PS: By the way, would you mind showing your SHOW PROFILE result?

Comment: Can't profile the query because I can't recreate the 98 seconds. The query runs in under a second for me right now. Are your remarks about the LEFT JOINs related to performance in any way?

Comment: That was my wonder, since if you transform the left join into an inner join from the beginning perhaps it would ease the engine's calculations. How come your query takes so little time now?

Comment: That's my question.

Comment: It could take longer because it coudl be doing the left joins and tehn the filtering, but what is critical about this is that you are getting the wrong dataset back. Left joins and inner jhoins are nto the same thing and you have convertedyour left joins to inner joins.